# Retrofit/OkHTTP/RxJava intermittent InterruptedIOException

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, okhttp, rx-android

I am using the following (out of date) libraries:

```
Retrofit: 1.9.0
OkHTTP: 2.3.0
RxAndroid: 0.24.0
```

I noticed that every once in a while I get the following stack trace for my POST request:

```
 D/Retrofit: ---> HTTP POST https:xxxxx
 D/Retrofit: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
 D/Retrofit: Content-Length: 396
 D/Retrofit: ---> END HTTP (396-byte body)
 D/Retrofit: ---- ERROR https:xxxxx
 I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 D/Retrofit: java.io.InterruptedIOException
   at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:146)
   at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:75)
   at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
   at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:201)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.flush(HttpConnection.java:140)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.makeTunnel(Connection.java:399)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:229)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:159)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:175)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:120)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:330)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:319)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:271)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:228)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:199)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
   at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
   at $Proxy1.replyTransaction(Unknown Source)
   < App Specific Trace > 
   at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:145)
   at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:137)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7304)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:62)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:47)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 D/Retrofit: ---- END ERROR
 retrofit.RetrofitError
     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395)
     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
     at $Proxy1.replyTransaction(Unknown Source)
     < App Specific Trace > 
     at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:145)
     at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:137)
     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7304)
     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:62)
     at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:47)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
  Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException
     at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:146)
     at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:75)
     at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
     at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:201)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.flush(HttpConnection.java:140)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.makeTunnel(Connection.java:399)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:229)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:159)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:175)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:120)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:330)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:319)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:271)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:228)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:199)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
     at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913) 
     at $Proxy1.replyTransaction(Unknown Source) 
     < App Specific Trace > 
     at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:145) 
     at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:137) 
     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7304) 
     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:62) 
     at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:47) 
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

My code for this is as follows:

Network call:

```
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
      @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
        try {
          subscriber.onNext(/* Sync network call here. */);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          subscriber.onError(e);
        }
        subscriber.onCompleted();
      }
    })
        .onBackpressureBuffer()
        // singleton for Schedulers.io()
        .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
        // singleton for AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
        .observeOn(mainThreadScheduler);
```

Which is called like so:

```
subscription = makeNetworkCall()
            .subscribe(new Observer<Object>() {
              @Override public void onNext(Object object) {
                // close and finish activity
              }
              @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
                // whoops!
              }
            });
```

and is unsubscribed from in the Activity like so:

```
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (subscription != null) {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
      subscription = null;
      if (condition) {
        finish();
      }
    }
  }
```

My understanding of this is that I am getting an `InterruptedException` because I am `unsubscribe()`ing from the `Subscription` in `onPause()`. We do this for other requests though so I am not sure why I am only seeing it here and why exactly it is happening.

To provide a bit more info on this, the network call happens from an Activity that is launched from the lock screen via a notification action to force the user to unlock their device in order to take action.

My question here is why is this happening and is there a good way to remediate this? According to a few articles, `onPause()` is where you should unsubscribe from `Observables`.

More info on this can be see [In okHTTP's github issues](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/931)

Thanks!

Comment: Beware that you're breaking the [Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html). If you invoke `onError` you **must not** invoke `onCompleted`

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but it may be that you are not checking if the subscriber is still there before emitting the interrupted exception.

Try this:

```
return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
      @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
        try {
          subscriber.onNext(/* Sync network call here. */);
          subscriber.onCompleted();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) { // <-- check before emitting error
            subscriber.onError(e);
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon unsubscription the chain need not do any more work as we don't care about the output anymore. We could just let the current operation complete, and stop the work cleanly when we reach the next operator, but why waste any resources we don't have to? If there's an ongoing network request we want to cancel it. We do this by interrupting the thread. If/when the code on this thread checks if it is interrupted then no more work need be done, and `InterruptedIOException` can be thrown.

Depending on exactly when unsubscribe is called you may or may not see the error. If unsubscribe is called well before the request has started loading or after it has finished then you may not see this error.

So the reason for this Exception is OkHttp wants to give up as soon as it knows you're not interested in its results and RxJava doesn't want to swallow it in-case it was important for you.

You can add a default error handler to suppress undeliverable `InterruptedException`s and `InterruptedIOException`s which are rarely useful. See [RxJava 2 Error Handling](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#error-handling), I believe RxJava 1 has a similar construct, but you should consider migrating to RxJava 2. It's really not much of a departure, and [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) has been updated to RxJava 2.

`onPause()` is not necessarily where you should unsubscribe. You should unsubscribe where the logic of your app demands it and where it will prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
return Observable.create(e -> {
           try {
               e.onNext(...);
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               e.tryOnError(ex);
           }
           e.onComplete();
       });
```

tryOnError() checks is the Observer is disposed or not when sending error.

reference: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4863